# Plone: how to create and associate (reference) items in-place with the dexterity framework

Tags: plone, dexterity

I've come across a couple use cases recently where I've wanted to create and associate (reference) items in-place. Please identify how I can achieve a "create and associate" pattern with the dexterity framework.

The "create and associate" pattern would allow an end user to create a new item and use that new item as a reference in the context of the current item. Most importantly, the user should never feel that they have fully left the context of the current item (or they should be immediately returned to that context).

I'll use a concrete example. Below is an animation from an application that does something similar. The relationship in the example is "invoice referencing a client", but it could easily have been "academic programme referencing a course".

[image: add item in place]

Comment: I guess no one is gonna implement this for you. imho it's possible since DX items could have relationships to other items. With Some ajax requests you also could achieve that the user feels like never leaving the current context.

Comment: You'd get quite close by adding an overlay form link for a DX item add form (e.g. in a portlet). See overlayhelpers.js and p.a.jquerytools README for details. After a new item is added, it should be available for relation field. Better integration would require a custom js-heavy z3c.form widget. I guess, out of the box is missing, because we can do simpler version of this just by allowing to add child items to a container (course items inside a programme container).

Comment: Mathias and Asko, this is enough information to get me started. A ready made widget would, of course, be ideal, but the overlay approach could work for me.